# How to flag data duplicates in an array as fast as possible in C?

Tags: c, arrays, performance

I have made half a program that does some major floating point math. Depending on the data it started with, it can generate very large arrays that describe line segments. The positions of these line segments are recorded using the Cartesian coordinate system with floating point numbers to record the X,Y,Z positions of each end of the line. I cant use X,Y,Z for both ends so I used X,Y,Z for the start, and Q,R,S for the end. So basically what I want to do, is flag all lines that are identical or flipped so that Q,R,S one line one is equal to X,Y,Z on line two and X,Y,Z on line one is equal to Q,R,S on line two. My current flagging technique is to set X to -1 because I know that none of the lines will ever end up with negative coordinates. I don't want to flag both lines, just all of them except for one. This is my current function:

```
int filter(int lines)
{
printf("Filtering...\n");
refline=0;
scanline=1;
while(refline<(lines))
    {
        if( segpointX[refline] == segpointQ[scanline] && segpointY[refline] == segpointR[scanline] && segpointZ[refline] == segpointS[scanline] && segpointQ[refline] == segpointX[scanline] && segpointR[refline] == segpointY[scanline] && segpointS[refline] == segpointZ[scanline] 
         || segpointX[refline] == segpointX[scanline] && segpointY[refline] == segpointY[scanline] && segpointZ[refline] == segpointZ[scanline] && segpointQ[refline] == segpointQ[scanline] && segpointR[refline] == segpointR[scanline] && segpointS[refline] == segpointS[scanline])
            {
                //printf("Origional: %f  %f  %f  ><  %f  %f  %f\n",segpointX[refline],segpointY[refline],segpointZ[refline],segpointQ[refline],segpointR[refline],segpointS[refline]);
                //printf("Duplicate: %f  %f  %f  ><  %f  %f  %f\n\n",segpointX[scanline],segpointY[scanline],segpointZ[scanline],segpointQ[scanline],segpointR[scanline],segpointS[scanline]);
                segpointX[scanline]=-1;
            }

         scanline++;

        if(scanline==lines+1)
            {
                refline++;
                scanline=refline+1;
            }   
    }
return(0);
}
```

I know how many lines I have, and that is what "lines" integer is. This code works exactly as it should, but its really slow compared to the rest of my program. I think there must be a way to do this faster, but I'm not sure how. It really is a shame to have this function because it drags down the rest of my program which is incredibly fast considering its all floating point math. If there is no decent way of making this around 3x faster than it is, I might just have to live with messed up data and make the next function smart enough to ignore it. Flagging the bad lines now would extremely helpful however, because the next function is complex enough as it is without trying to compensate for duplicates in my data.

Comment: Is it important which side of the line stays in XYZ/QRS? Incidentally, unless your work is mostly on single coordinates (e.g. you process first all the Xs, then all the Ys, ...) you should use a single array of a suitable `struct` to improve data locality and avoid cache misses (besides, you get more understandable code).

Comment: No, It does not matter which end is X,Y,Z Q,R,S. All that matters right now, is that the X is set to -1 if theres a duplicate line found

Comment: Put your intervals into something like a binary search tree as you go, it will make searching for the duplicates much quicker (N*log(N) i/o O(N^2)). May be look here for the inspiration: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html

Comment: Duplicates are found typically in O(N) using a hash table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical method to flag duplicates in an array is to sort the array in some way (O(N·logN)) and then flag/remove consecutive identical elements in a single pass (O(N)); this has total complexity O(N·logN), while your approach is O(N<sup>2</sup>).

In your case, all the difficulty boils down to establishing some kind of ordering relation between your data points.

First of all, I would normalize the format of your lines, so that equivalent lines (same endpoints) are represented in the same way. To do this, for each line compare the tuples (XYZ)/(QRS); if Q is less than X, then the QRS are swapped with XYZ; if X==Q, Y and R are checked, and if they are equal again Z with S.

At the end of this O(N) pass, all the equivalent lines have the same XYZQRS representation.

Now, if you don't want to change the representation of your data (6 independent arrays, where a single array of `struct`s would be simpler and more efficient), it's easier to sort an array of indexes instead of the actual data (also, it may be more efficient, or even the only viable possibility if you don't want to change the ordering of your actual data). Initialize an array of integers with numbers from 0 to `lines-1`; then, you can use the `qsort` function to do the sorting, passing your custom comparer function.

This function will receive the indexes to be compared; you'll use these indexes to access the corresponding XYZ/QRS and to compare them in order (compare the X of the first element with the X of the second element, if they are equal go on to Ys, and so on). At the end of the sort, your index array will be sorted, with the identical items standing nearby.

Now you can do the final pass: scan the indexes array, and compare the element corresponding to the current index to the one of the next index: if they are equal, you mark the first one as a duplicate; otherwise, you either are at a the last item of a duplicates sequence or you are at the start of a new sequence, so you'll want to (at least temporarily) keep this item. Since the items are ordered, the identical ones are all in a row, so you can mark them in a single pass.

---

Notice that this will work correctly only if you want *exact* matches - i.e. it won't take in account FP inaccuracies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think sorting the data will work out good for my situation. Hopefully tomorrow I can try this out

Comment: I would consider paying special attention to the exact matches issue. fp "equal" comparisons are tricky. +1 @MatteoItalia.  see: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is `N^2`. You should be able to do this in `N log N`. However the complexity required to get to `N log N` will depend on your data to some extent.

Here's how I'd do it assuming that your data is well distributed in the X direction.

1. For each line segment flip it if required so that X < Q. - this is O(N).
2. Sort all the line segments by X - this is O(N log N).
3. Duplicates will now be adjacent so a simple scan can remove them.

This is not 100% correct but gets the rough jist correct - you need to handle some degenerate cases..

1. What do you do is X==Q at the flip stage. (Ans. Flip based on Y/Q. if thats equal too then use Z/S)
2. What do you do if two segments have the same X in the sort phase. (Ans. Use Y, Z, Q, R, S as secondary keys in that order.)